# "Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON" error in Next.js

Tags: redirect, next.js, next.js13

In my Next.js project, I have a password reset form as shown below:

[image]

When users enter their email, a POST request is sent to the `/api/request-password-reset` route:

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { db } from "@/lib/firebase-admin";

const RESPONSE_MESSAGES = {
  USER_NOT_FOUND: "User not found",
  EMAIL_NOT_VERIFIED: "User not registered",
  PASSWORD_RESET_LINK_SENT: "Password reset link sent",
};

export async function POST(request: NextRequest) {
  try {
    const { email: userEmail } = await request.json();

    // Check whether the user is new or already exists
    const userRef = db.collection("credentialUsers");
    const snapshot = await userRef.where("email", "==", userEmail).get();

    // 1. If the snapshot is empty, then the user does not exist.
    if (snapshot.empty) {
      return NextResponse.json({ message: RESPONSE_MESSAGES.USER_NOT_FOUND });
    }

    const userData = snapshot.docs[0].data();
    const { email, emailVerified } = userData;

    // 2. If the snapshot is not empty and emailVerified is false
    if (email === userEmail && emailVerified === false) {
      return NextResponse.json({
        message: RESPONSE_MESSAGES.EMAIL_NOT_VERIFIED,
      });
    }

    // 3. If the user exists and the emailVerified field is true
    if (email === userEmail && emailVerified === true) {
      const redirectUrl = new URL(
        "/request-password-reset-message",
        request.url
      );
      return NextResponse.redirect(redirectUrl);
    }
    
  } catch (error) {
    return NextResponse.json({ status: 500 });
  }
}
```

As you can see, when a user enters an email address that exists in database and the email is verified, I am uisng `NextResponse.redirect()` to redirect the user to the `/request-password-reset-message` route, where I show a message that says "Password reset instructions sent to your email."

Here is the component that shows the message:

```
export default function RequestPasswordResetPage() {
  return (
    <div className="mb-12 mt-32">
      <p className="text-center text-green-600">
        Password reset instructions sent to your email.
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Currently, when I enter my email (which exists in database and is verified), instead of getting redirected to the `/request-password-reset-message` route, I get an error message that says: `Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON`.

[image]

I have no idea why this is happening.

When I check the Network tab and click on `request-password-reset` I see that the redirect has been successful.

[image]

[image]

But when I click on `request-password-reset-message` and then check the response, I see the following:

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html id="__next_error__">
    <head>
        <meta charSet="utf-8"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
        <script src="/_next/static/chunks/polyfills.js" noModule=""></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js" async=""></script>
        <script src="/_next/static/chunks/main-app.js" async=""></script>
        <script>
            (self.__next_f = self.__next_f || []).push([0])
        </script>
        <script>
            self.__next_f.push([1, "1:HL[\"/_next/static/css/app/layout.css?v=1694105486774\",{\"as\":\"style\"}]\n0:\"$L2\"\n"])
        </script>
        <script>
            self.__next_f.push([1, "3:I{\"id\":\"(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/app-router.js?b7d60\",\"chunks\":[\"app-client-internals:static/chunks/app-client-internals.js\"],\"name\":\"\",\"async\":false}\n5:I{\"id\":\"(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/error-boundary.js?b9690\",\"chunks\":[\"app-client-internals:static/chunks/app-client-internals.js\"],\"name\":\"\",\"async\":false}\n6:I{\"id\":\"(app-client)/./lib/providers/next-auth-provider.tsx\",\"chunks\":[\"app/layout:static/chunks/app/layout.js\"],\"name\":\"NextAuthProvider\""])
        </script>
        <script>
            self.__next_f.push([1, ",\"async\":false}\n7:I{\"id\":\"(app-client)/./node_modules/nextjs-toploader/dist/index.js\",\"chunks\":[\"app/layout:static/chunks/app/layout.js\"],\"name\":\"\",\"async\":false}\n8:I{\"id\":\"(app-client)/./components/main-nav.tsx\",\"chunks\":[\"app/layout:static/chunks/app/layout.js\"],\"name\":\"\",\"async\":false}\na:I{\"id\":\"(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js\",\"chunks\":[\"app-client-internals:static/chunks/app-client-internals.js\"],\"name\":\"\",\"async\":false}\nb:I{\"id\":\"(app-client)/./node_modules/nex"])
        </script>
        <script>
            self.__next_f.push([1, "t/dist/client/components/render-from-template-context.js\",\"chunks\":[\"app-client-internals:static/chunks/app-client-internals.js\"],\"name\":\"\",\"async\":false}\n"])
        </script>
        <script>
            self.__next_f.push([1, "2:[[[\"$\",\"link\",\"0\",{\"rel\":\"stylesheet\",\"href\":\"/_next/static/css/app/layout.css?v=1694105486774\",\"precedence\":\"next_static/css/app/layout.css\"}]],[\"$\",\"$L3\",null,{\"buildId\":\"development\",\"assetPrefix\":\"\",\"initialCanonicalUrl\":\"/request-password-reset-message\",\"initialTree\":[\"\",{\"children\":[\"request-password-reset-message\",{\"children\":[\"__PAGE__\",{}]}]},\"$undefined\",\"$undefined\",true],\"initialHead\":[\"$L4\",null],\"globalErrorComponent\":\"$5\",\"notFound\":[\"$\",\"html\",null,{\"lang\":\"en\",\"children\":[\"$\",\"body\",null,{\"className\":\"__className_0ec1f4 relative flex min-h-screen flex-col\",\"children\":[\"$\",\"$L6\",null,{\"children\":[[\"$\",\"$L7\",null,{\"showSpinner\":false,\"shadow\":false}],[\"$\",\"header\",null,{\"className\":\"container fixed left-1/2 top-0 z-[100] max-w-screen-2xl -translate-x-1/2 transform backdrop-blur-sm\",\"children\":[\"$\",\"$L8\",null,{}]}],[\"$\",\"main\",null,{\"className\":\"flex-1\",\"children\":[\"$L9\",\"$undefined\",[[\"$\",\"title\",null,{\"children\":\"404: This page could not be found.\"}],[\"$\",\"div\",null,{\"style\":{\"fontFamily\":\"system-ui,\\\"Segoe UI\\\",Roboto,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif,\\\"Apple Color Emoji\\\",\\\"Segoe UI Emoji\\\"\",\"height\":\"100vh\",\"textAlign\":\"center\",\"display\":\"flex\",\"flexDirection\":\"column\",\"alignItems\":\"center\",\"justifyContent\":\"center\"},\"children\":[\"$\",\"div\",null,{\"children\":[[\"$\",\"style\",null,{\"dangerouslySetInnerHTML\":{\"__html\":\"body{color:#000;background:#fff;margin:0}.next-error-h1{border-right:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.3)}@media (prefers-color-scheme:dark){body{color:#fff;background:#000}.next-error-h1{border-right:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.3)}}\"}}],[\"$\",\"h1\",null,{\"className\":\"next-error-h1\",\"style\":{\"display\":\"inline-block\",\"margin\":\"0 20px 0 0\",\"padding\":\"0 23px 0 0\",\"fontSize\":24,\"fontWeight\":500,\"verticalAlign\":\"top\",\"lineHeight\":\"49px\"},\"children\":\"404\"}],[\"$\",\"div\",null,{\"style\":{\"display\":\"inline-block\"},\"children\":[\"$\",\"h2\",null,{\"style\":{\"fontSize\":14,\"fontWeight\":400,\"lineHeight\":\"49px\",\"margin\":0},\"children\":\"This page could not be found.\"}]}]]}]}]]]}],[\"$\",\"footer\",null,{\"children\":[\"$\",\"div\",null,{\"className\":\"container flex h-20 max-w-screen-2xl items-center justify-center border-t border-neutral-200\",\"children\":[\"$\",\"p\",null,{\"className\":\"text-center text-sm\",\"children\":\"Built with Next.js by Hemanta Sundaray\"}]}]}]]}]}]}],\"asNotFound\":false,\"children\":[[\"$\",\"html\",null,{\"lang\":\"en\",\"children\":[\"$\",\"body\",null,{\"className\":\"__className_0ec1f4 relative flex min-h-screen flex-col\",\"children\":[\"$\",\"$L6\",null,{\"children\":[[\"$\",\"$L7\",null,{\"showSpinner\":false,\"shadow\":false}],[\"$\",\"header\",null,{\"className\":\"container fixed left-1/2 top-0 z-[100] max-w-screen-2xl -translate-x-1/2 transform backdrop-blur-sm\",\"children\":[\"$\",\"$L8\",null,{}]}],[\"$\",\"main\",null,{\"className\":\"flex-1\",\"children\":[\"$\",\"$La\",null,{\"parallelRouterKey\":\"children\",\"segmentPath\":[\"children\"],\"error\":\"$undefined\",\"errorStyles\":\"$undefined\",\"loading\":\"$undefined\",\"loadingStyles\":\"$undefined\",\"hasLoading\":false,\"template\":[\"$\",\"$Lb\",null,{}],\"templateStyles\":\"$undefined\",\"notFound\":\"$undefined\",\"notFoundStyles\":\"$undefined\",\"childProp\":{\"current\":[\"$\",\"$La\",null,{\"parallelRouterKey\":\"children\",\"segmentPath\":[\"children\",\"request-password-reset-message\",\"children\"],\"error\":\"$undefined\",\"errorStyles\":\"$undefined\",\"loading\":\"$undefined\",\"loadingStyles\":\"$undefined\",\"hasLoading\":false,\"template\":[\"$\",\"$Lb\",null,{}],\"templateStyles\":\"$undefined\",\"notFound\":\"$undefined\",\"notFoundStyles\":\"$undefined\",\"childProp\":{\"current\":[[\"$\",\"div\",null,{\"className\":\"mb-12 mt-32\",\"children\":[\"$\",\"p\",null,{\"className\":\"text-center text-green-600\",\"children\":\"Password reset instructions sent to your email.\"}]}],null],\"segment\":\"__PAGE__\"},\"styles\":[]}],\"segment\":\"request-password-reset-message\"},\"styles\":[]}]}],[\"$\",\"footer\",null,{\"children\":[\"$\",\"div\",null,{\"className\":\"container flex h-20 max-w-screen-2xl items-center justify-center border-t border-neutral-200\",\"children\":[\"$\",\"p\",null,{\"className\":\"text-center text-sm\",\"children\":\"Built with Next.js by Hemanta Sundaray\"}]}]}]]}]}]}],null]}]]\n"])
        </script>
        <script>
            self.__next_f.push([1, "9:[[\"$\",\"meta\",\"0\",{\"charSet\":\"utf-8\"}],[\"$\",\"meta\",\"1\",{\"name\":\"viewport\",\"content\":\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\"}]]\n4:[[\"$\",\"meta\",\"0\",{\"charSet\":\"utf-8\"}],[\"$\",\"title\",\"1\",{\"children\":\"Hemanta Sundaray\"}],[\"$\",\"meta\",\"2\",{\"name\":\"description\",\"content\":\"My website\"}],[\"$\",\"meta\",\"3\",{\"name\":\"viewport\",\"content\":\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\"}],[\"$\",\"link\",\"4\",{\"rel\":\"icon\",\"href\":\"/favicon.ico\",\"type\":\"image/x-icon\",\"sizes\":\"any\"}]]\n"])
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I would appreciate any help in figuring out why I am not getting redirected to the page and instead getting an error message.

The following is my RequestPasswordReset form:

```
"use client";

import * as React from "react";
import { zodResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/zod";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import * as z from "zod";

import { cn } from "@/lib/util";
import { forgotPasswordSchema } from "@/lib/validations/auth";
import { buttonVariants } from "@/components/ui/button";
import { Input } from "@/components/ui/input";
import { Label } from "@/components/ui/label";
import { Icons } from "@/components/icons";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { requestPasswordReset } from "@/lib/request-password-reset";

export type FormData = z.infer<typeof forgotPasswordSchema>;

export function RequestPasswordResetForm() {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    reset,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm<FormData>({ resolver: zodResolver(forgotPasswordSchema) });

  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = React.useState<boolean>(false);
  const [error, setError] = React.useState<string | null>(null);

  const router = useRouter();

  async function onSubmit(submittedData: FormData) {
    await requestPasswordReset({
      submittedData,
      setError,
      setIsLoading,
      reset,
      router,
    });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {error && (
        <p className="mb-5 text-sm text-red-500 animate-in fade-in-0 slide-in-from-left-1">
          {error}
        </p>
      )}
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <div className="grid gap-6">
          <div className="grid gap-1">
            <Label htmlFor="email">Email</Label>
            <Input
              id="email"
              type="email"
              placeholder="name@example.com"
              autoCapitalize="none"
              autoComplete="email"
              autoCorrect="off"
              disabled={isLoading}
              {...register("email")}
            />
            {errors.email && (
              <p className="px-1 text-xs text-red-600 animate-in fade-in-0 slide-in-from-left-1">
                {errors.email.message}
              </p>
            )}
          </div>
          <button className={cn(buttonVariants())} disabled={isLoading}>
            {isLoading && (
              <Icons.spinner className="mr-2 h-4 w-4 animate-spin" />
            )}
            Request password reset
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And the following is the requestPasswordReset() function:

```
import type { FormData } from "@/components/request-password-reset-form";

const RESPONSE_MESSAGES = {
  USER_NOT_FOUND: "User not found",
  EMAIL_NOT_VERIFIED: "User not registered",
  PASSWORD_RESET: "Password reset",
  PASSWORD_RESET_FAILURE: "Password reset failed. Please try again.",
};

interface RequestPasswordResetProps {
  submittedData: FormData;
  setError: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string | null>>;
  reset: () => void;
  setIsLoading: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>;
  router: any;
}

export async function requestPasswordReset({
  submittedData,
  setError,
  reset,
  setIsLoading,
  router,
}: RequestPasswordResetProps) {
  setIsLoading(true);
  setError(null);

  try {
    // Attempt to reset the user password
    const resetResponse = await fetch("/api/request-password-reset", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(submittedData),
    });

    // Reset failed
    if (!resetResponse.ok) {
      throw new Error(RESPONSE_MESSAGES.PASSWORD_RESET_FAILURE);
    }

    const resetResponseData = await resetResponse.json();

    // Handle different server responses
    if (resetResponseData.message === RESPONSE_MESSAGES.USER_NOT_FOUND) {
      setError(RESPONSE_MESSAGES.USER_NOT_FOUND);
      reset();
      return;
    }

    if (resetResponseData.message === RESPONSE_MESSAGES.EMAIL_NOT_VERIFIED) {
      setError(RESPONSE_MESSAGES.EMAIL_NOT_VERIFIED);
      reset();
      return;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    setError((error as Error).message);
  } finally {
    setIsLoading(false);
  }
}
```

Comment: Would you share how to send data to the sever?

Comment: @MenaiAlaEddine-Aladdin Have added the code

Comment: probably just classic parse error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to misunderstand what a redirect does.

A redirect means "You asked for something, you should ask for it from this URL instead".

You seem to think it means "Navigate the viewport to this  URL", which it doesn't.

---

You have written some JavaScript which makes an HTTP request to `/api/request-password-reset` and expects to get some JSON back. Instead it gets a redirect to `/request-password-reset-message`. This is fine. It then makes an HTTP request to to `/request-password-reset-message` and **still expects to get JSON back**, but it gets an HTML document back instead.

You should either:

- Make a regular HTML form submission without using JS in the first place *or*
- Change `/api/request-password-reset` to respond with JSON and then display the content on request-password-reset-message using JS instead of loading it as a new page.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I misunderstood what a redirect does. Now, I will have to handle the redirection at the client-side.

Comment: import `next/navigation` then use redirect method.